# What is the point of 'protected' in a union in C++

Tags: c++, unions

Is there anything that protected members or functions can be used for?

You cannot inherit from a union so there are no children that can access it.  Does it provide a functional use or is just there because removing it was hassle?

Comment: It'e there for completeness.

Comment: @StoryTeller Elaborate!  :-)

Comment: @user1158692, there's nothing to elaborate. It's the same sort of completeness that protected and private inheritance give you. It may be completely useless, but the formal language has a complete set of terms.

Comment: @StoryTeller, are you saying that protected and private inheritance are completely useless?

Comment: @Stefn, not quite. But if you find yourself inheriting privately, you may want to rethink your design to do composition instead.

Comment: @StoryTeller, so they are not useless but are rarely required?  That I agree with.  I wanted to make sure it was not the same with the protected level in a union.

Comment: @Stefan, I wouldn't say they are ever required, only not completely useless (which means they have their uses, but those uses have better alternatives). As for protected union members... I see no use whatsoever.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`protected` in a `union` becomes completely equivalent to `private`, but this allowance does no harm and avoids extra special case handling and extra differences between `union` and `struct`/`class` (which are described all together in the standard).

Honestly, I think it's possible to use `protected` in a `union` just not to add the umteenth special case to the standard for the sake of it; maybe it didn't even come to mind to the standard committee to differentiate this behavior, since it's quite a bizarre corner case but does no harm as it's currently specified.

Comment: So it is just in there because it was more hassle than it was worth to remove it?

Comment: @Stefan: I would say so; why bother with creating special cases? (ok, well, this is C++ and there are special cases and UB for everything, but the point stands)